# Infared Detector USB POLL

Tags: c#, c++, usb

My goal is to use c++/c# to poll a usb port to see if power is flowing through from the out to in.

I have a infared detector led connected to the usb output and then back to the input. I basically want to know how I could do something like this:

```
USBDevice usb = LoadUSBDevice(port1);
boolean detected = usb:isPowerFlowingOutToIn();
if(detected){
     double amount = usb:getVoltage();
     if(amount > somenumber){
           //do stuff
     }
}
```

Comment: You need to read infrared detector documentation. Usually such devices are shipped with driver with known programming interface. For example, infrared device may be accessed as a socket or virtual COM port from user mode program.

Comment: `usb::getVoltage` isn't needed, that's just 5 Volt. You probably wanted `getCurrent`.

Answer (score 0):

This setup can't work as-is. USB devices have to respond per the USB specs, or they won't get an address assigned. Since your device isn't behaving properly (e.g. it fails to establish Vendor ID, Product ID, device class, ...) it won't get an address. Therefore, the hypothetical `LoadUSBDevice(port1);` won't work.

Raymond Chen summarized this nicely as "a fork is a non-standard USB device, too". The Windows USB drivers are reasonably forgiving, but you can't just expect anything to work when plugged into a USB port.